# Add Customs column to Admin > sales >order

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, order-grid

i am try to add columns in Admin > sales >order by overriding method.
Copy
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php 
to
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php.

add this code in protected function _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ", ")')));
```

add this code in protected function _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
        'index' => 'name',
    ));
```

but it get all get all product's name of all orders like in the image
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.name SEPARATOR ", ")` will display all item order as name

Comment: @R.S i don't understanding u waht u want to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take look at [Show SKU and Product Name in Sales_Order_Grid?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14341/show-sku-and-product-name-in-sales-order-grid)

You can do this one of two ways :

1) Using "renderer"

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
    ....                                        
    'renderer' => 'NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Productsname',          
));


class NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Productsname extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {                    
        $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row->getData('entity_id'));              
        $str="";

        foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item){                      
            $str .= $_item->getSku();
    }       
        unset($order);
        return $str;
    }
}
```

2) using "join" see https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14343/519

Comment: at which location, I have to create a render file and with which name ?

Comment: You seem to be making changes to core (which you should not) instead create a custom module see http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/adding-customer-group-column-to-sales-grid-in-magento/ and http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

Comment: no i am not editing core file, i am overriding core file by Copy /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php.

Comment: i am using render method with this code class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productsname extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {                    
        $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row->getData('entity_id'));              
        $str="";

        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_item){                      
            $str .= $_item->getSku();
    }       
        unset($order);
        return $str;
    }
} but it repeat last product two times

Comment: Update your question with your code in a readable format

Comment: new question link for the repeating product name problem

Comment: how to get a column with custom attribute(like publisher name) in sales > order grid

Comment: Can you create a new question? You can do it one of two ways (1) create a new field in sale item and store it when the product is added to cart (2) load the product in real time from the order item and look it up

Comment: new question link for the repeating product name problem   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42576/having-problem-to-add-new-column-in-admin-sales-order-grid-product-name-is-r

Comment: already accepted :) but how to get custom attribute which created by me(like publisher of book)

Comment: Can you create a new question for custom attribute and explain where you want to put it and which of the two methods list above you want to use (note #2 as you update these product fields the attribute will change on your order. so the data may be different from time of order)

Comment: link of new ques http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/add-new-column-with-custom-attribute-in-sales-order-grid