# Having problem to add new column in admin >sales > order grid ,product name is repeating

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, order-grid

I am try to add columns in `Admin > sales >order by overriding method.`

Copied

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

& **using Renderer, created Renderer** at

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Renderer/Productsname.php
```

but getting some product repeating like in the image
I add following code in `Grid.php` to protected function `_prepareColumns()`

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('NAME'),
        'index' => 'productname',
        'type' => 'text',
        'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productsname',
    ));
```

& following code in **Productsname.php**

```
    <?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productsname extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {                    
        $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row->getData('entity_id'));              
        $str="";

        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_item){                      
            $str .= $_item->getname()."<br>";
    }       
        unset($order);
        return $str;
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Any grouped, configurable or bundle products involved?

Comment: Did you try getAllVisibleItems() instead of getAllItems()?

Comment: @R.S. I think you can put your comment as an answer if you make it look like an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$order->getAllVisibleItems()
```

**getAllVisibleItems()** - will show you only the parent item

**getAllItem()** -  will show both products (config and simple)

See [Magento – What is the difference between getAllVisibleItems() and getAllItems()?](http://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/magento-what-is-the-difference-between-getallvisibleitems-and-getallitems/)