# add new column with custom attribute in sales > order grid in Magento ver. 1.9.3.3

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, sales-order, order-grid

**Magento ver. 1.9.3.3**

I am trying  to add columns with **custom product attribute **(like publisher which was created by me) in `Admin > sales >order`.

Copied

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

**& create Renderer at**

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Renderer/Productspublisher.php
```

code in **Productspublisher.php**

```
    <?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productspublisher extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {                    
       $_item = $this->getItem());
       $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
       $str="";
       foreach($product as $item)
       {
         $str .= $item->getAttributeText('publisher');
       }

        unset($product);
        return $str;
    }
}
?>
```

code in protected function **_prepareColumns()** of `Grid.php`

```
$this->addColumn('publisher', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Publisher'),
        'index' => 'publisher',
        'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productspublisher',
    ));
```

but getting error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in
>   sitedomain.com\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Renderer\Productspublisher.php
>   on line 6

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code in Productspublisher.php

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productspublisher extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {                    

          $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row->getData('entity_id'));              
        $str="";

        foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item){  
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());                    
            $str .= $product->getAttributeText('publisher')."<br>";
    }       

        unset($order);
        return $str;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried what is suggested above , But in my case , i am not getting the data from database,  Here is the  my question can you plz help me out to solve the error. [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179494/i-want-to-add-new-column-with-custom-attribute-in-sales-order-grid-magento-ver

Answer (score 1):

Following a blog post from atwix about [ADDING A COLUMN TO MAGENTO ORDERS GRID - ALTERNATIVE WAY USING LAYOUT HANDLES](http://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/)

I would suggest you need a module that does the following.

Listens to the admin event `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` and then adds the correct attribute/join to the sales_order collection.

```
public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    // Now you can add attributes to select or join onto this collection
}
```

Add the correct column using a layout file for the module.

```
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>column_id</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Column Title</header>
                    <index>column_attribute</index>
                    <filter_index>column_attribute</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                </arguments>
                <after>shipping_name</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

I have not tried this myself but from reading through the complete blog post it seems not only very due-able but also a very nice approach without any rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

There is serious error in your codes. What do you mean by this:

```
$order=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getData('getProductId'));
```

You are loading a product model here and assuming it is order object ?

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_item){
```

You cannot call getAllItems() on a product object. Its a function of order model. If you share what you are trying to achieve, I can help you.