# How to add new columns to my orders' dashboard?

Tags: orders, configuration, dashboard, column

I'd like that in my orders dashboard (attached) I'd have one extra column informing which 'discount cupom' was used in that order (if any).

In the attached file you can see how my orders' dashboard looks like in the moment. Although it's not in english you can figure out what I'm talking about. Can I add another column in there? How so?

I'm running version 1.9.0.1.

Thanks a million!

Cheers

Lelo

[image: ...]

Comment: Interested in the same.

Comment: FYI, there are several extensions that do this.

Comment: Check out this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/add-new-column-with-custom-attribute-in-sales-order-grid and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/add-column-to-admin-sales-orders-grid

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl although the order grid brings the additional problem, that you need to add the values to the `order_grid` table.

The alternative to copy the values would be to join the order table into the collection.